# How would I do this on Windows CMD?

Tags: linux, windows, cmd, magento2

How would I do this in Windows cmd:

```
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +

find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +

chown -R :www-data . # Ubuntu

chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Comment: That is Linux. This is Windows.

Comment: I know, I'm asking what the Windows equivalent is, though

Comment: switch to linux

Comment: If you're wondering how to set up Magento on Windows, please look that up and ask [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) if you have any issues. StackOverflow itself is more for specific programming questions (asking people to port a script for you is not considered specific)

Comment: I'm sorry, I was hoping someone who knew both could help me. I didn't realize the communities were so mutually exclusive. I've fixed my tags, hopefully it'll help.

Comment: I'm not sure that doing this on Windows will in any way help to run Magento on Windows, so if that's your goal you should really start there instead of with the Linux instructions

Comment: I've been following these instruction so far: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/composer.html. I've posted on superuser as per your advice, though. Thank you.

Comment: Please regard that Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, neither is it a free translation service! Please take the [tour] and read these help articles: [ask] and [mcve]!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what the command does, may or may not doable on a Windows due to different ACL mechanism.

The following command basically finds all files from the given paths and give "group" write access.

```
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
```

In Windows, or says the file system, a file or a directory can only have 1 owner, a user or a group, but only 1, you can use the command line `icacls.exe` to add groups or users `write` access. However, this is not based on "ownership". run `icacls /?` to check out the examples at the end of the help document. The command is really useful and a little tricky to use at the first time.
Surely you still can change the owner's access by using `CREATOR GROUP` or `CREATOR OWNER` (built-in)

```
icacls "path name" /grant "creator owner":F /T /Q
```

I normally prefer

```
icacls "path name" /grant "domain\group":F /T /Q
```

The following command changes the group owner of the current directory,

```
chown -R :www-data . # Ubuntu
```

Similar in Windows could be

```
icacls.exe "path name" /setowner username
```

The following command grants the owner of the file access to execute the file.
In the Windows, the access is kind `hidden`, in most of the case, you just need a general `read` access to the file and if the file is executable, you can easily call it by double click (with a executable extension `.exe`, `.com` etc.) or use `start` command in cmd.

The `x` access you can find from the advanced tab of `security`, called `execute`, the access can be managed by `icacls.exe` as well.

```
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Similar in Windows

```
icacls "path name" /grant "creator owner":RX
```

Seems everything is based on the command tool `icacls`, yes it is powerful.